# vue + core-js on windows os: Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object '#<Object>'

Tags: windows, vue.js, vuejs2, build, core-js

I can't build a Vue app on a windows machine but I can build it without problems on a Linux machine. I've tried all the solutions that I could find online and are applicable in my case but nothing works.

```
    ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors

    Error: C:\Users\Administrator\www\app\fe/node_modules/core-js/modules/_is-object.js?:5
    module.exports = function (it) {
                    ^
    TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object '#<Object>'

    - _is-object.js?:5 Module.eval
        [.]/[core-js]/modules/_is-object.js?:5:16

    - _is-object.js?:8 eval
        [.]/[core-js]/modules/_is-object.js?:8:30

    - index.html:1136 Module../node_modules/core-js/modules/_is-object.js
        C:/Users/Administrator/www/app/fe/public/index.html:1136:1

    - index.html:21 __webpack_require__
        C:/Users/Administrator/www/app/fe/public/index.html:21:30

    - _inherit-if-required.js?:1 eval
        [.]/[core-js]/modules/_inherit-if-required.js?:1:16

    - index.html:1112 Object../node_modules/core-js/modules/_inherit-if-required.js
        C:/Users/Administrator/www/app/fe/public/index.html:1112:1

    - index.html:21 __webpack_require__
        C:/Users/Administrator/www/app/fe/public/index.html:21:30

    - es6.regexp.constructor.js?:3 eval
        [.]/[core-js]/modules/es6.regexp.constructor.js?:3:25

    - index.html:1623 Object../node_modules/core-js/modules/es6.regexp.constructor.js
        C:/Users/Administrator/www/app/fe/public/index.html:1623:1

    - index.html:21 __webpack_require__
        C:/Users/Administrator/www/app/fe/public/index.html:21:30


        ERROR  Build failed with errors.
        npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
        npm ERR! errno 1
        npm ERR! app@0.1.0 build: `vue-cli-service build "--mode=test"`
        npm ERR! Exit status 1
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Failed at the app@0.1.0 build script.
    npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging 
    output above.

    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-06-26T06_48_04_957Z-debug.log
    PS C:\Users\Administrator\www\app\fe>
```

This is the package.json

```
    {
      "name": "app",
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "private": true,
      "scripts": {
        "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
        "build": "vue-cli-service build",
        "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
        "lint:style": "vue-cli-service lint:style --no-fix",
        "lint:style:fix": "vue-cli-service lint:style"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "apexcharts": "^3.25.0",
        "axios": "^0.19.0",
        "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
        "core-js": "^2.6.12",
        "filepond": "^4.25.1",
        "marked": "^1.2.9",
        "moment": "^2.29.1",
        "register-service-worker": "^1.7.2",
        "text-mask-addons": "^3.8.0",
        "v-calendar": "^0.9.7",
        "vee-validate": "^2.2.13",
        "velocity-animate": "^1.5.2",
        "vue": "^2.6.12",
        "vue-apexcharts": "^1.6.0",
        "vue-filepond": "^5.1.2",
        "vue-meta": "^2.4.0",
        "vue-router": "^3.5.1",
        "vue-router-multiguard": "^1.0.3",
        "vue-text-mask": "^6.1.2",
        "vue2-datepicker": "^2.12.0",
        "vue2-notify": "^1.4.0",
        "vuedraggable": "^2.24.3",
        "vuex": "^3.6.2",
        "vuex-i18n": "^1.13.1"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@ascendancyy/vue-cli-plugin-stylelint": "^1.1.2",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-shorthand-properties": "^7.12.13",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.16",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.9.0",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^3.9.0",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-pwa": "^3.9.0",
        "@vue/cli-service": "^3.9.0",
        "@vue/eslint-config-standard": "^4.0.0",
        "autoprefixer": "^9.8.6",
        "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
        "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-template-literals": "^6.22.0",
        "eslint": "^6.6.0",
        "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "^17.1.0",
        "eslint-plugin-strict-vue": "^1.0.0",
        "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.0.0",
        "lint-staged": "^8.1.5",
        "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
        "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
        "stylelint": "^11.1.1",
        "stylelint-config-standard": "^18.2.0",
        "stylelint-scss": "^3.19.0",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.12",
        "webpack-notifier": "^1.13.0"
      }
    }
```

I've spent a lot of hours and I'm losing it.
The project was initially built on Linux almost two years ago and I never had any problems. Now I've got a new customer and people there want to run the app on a Windows machine so I don't have any other option.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it. It seems that the problem was in webpack's rule in the vue.config.js file. I removed it and then I could build the app.

```
module.exports = {
    ...
    configureWebpack: {
        ...
        module: {
            rules: [
            // THIS PART WAS REMOVED AND I CAN NOW BUILD THE APP
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: "babel-loader"
                    }
                ],
                // Exclude the untransformed packages from the exclude rule here
                exclude: /node_modules\/(?!(@mypackage\/mypackage)\/).*/
            }
        ]
    }
    ...
}
```